# H2 database throwing an unexpected JdbcSQLException on CREATE SEQUENCE

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, h2

I am trying to write an in-memory database in order to test my DAO objects. I get the following stack trace :

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement " CREATE SEQUENCE CE0AOFQ AS[*] BIGINT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1"; SQL statement:
 CREATE SEQUENCE CE0AOFQ AS BIGINT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 [42000-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:191)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:534)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:261)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:578)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:519)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcStatement.java:132)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcStatement.java:121)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.executeSqlScript(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:169)
```

When trying to execute this command into a file called `init.sql`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE CE0AOFQ AS BIGINT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

As far as I checked ([here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/sequences.php), for example), this query seems correct.

Any idea why this is not working ?

Comment: That link is for sql server... but you are using h2. Try [this](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_sequence) documentation instead

Comment: I guessed they would use pretty much the same syntax ? Table creation and insertion works perfectly fine.

Comment: There's always little differences. Best to use the h2 docs and not the SQL server docs

Comment: Indeed, the syntax is slightly different. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify the datatype of a sequence in h2. It is always BIGINT.

Use:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE CE0AOFQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Comment: Was just about to answer myself thanks to lance-java. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling (like me) with H2 databse syntax, follow [lance-java](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1089967/lance-java)'s advice and read the actual [H2 grammar documentation](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html). You may find good advices, for example:

> Creates a new sequence. The data type of a sequence is BIGINT. Used values are never re-used, even when the transaction is rolled back.

Which means you cannot change it.